# Why is Apply[F[_]] So Slow?

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative

For the purposes of a unit test, I needed to zip the contents of 5 lists together. I had one test case that was never completing. I managed to track it down to the use of Apply[List].apply5 from the scalaz library. I'm assuming that my use of apply5 is not recommended in this case (only if I want my code to run to completion :-) ). I'd like to know why this is the case mainly to expand my knowledge and also to avoid a similar situation in the future. Note that each list is **guaranteed** to be the same length.

Below is the use of apply5 and below that is the code that I used instead (which runs quickly to completion).

```
// This works, but runs extremely slow
def zip5UsingApply[A](l1: List[A], l2: List[A], l3: List[A], l4: List[A], l5: List[A]): List[(A, (A, (A, (A, A))))] =
Apply[List].apply5(l1, l2, l3, l4, l5)((a, b, c, d, e) => (a, (b, (c, (d, e)))))

// Relaced the above with four 'helpers' and the 'zip5' at the bottom
def lzip2[A](f1: => List[A], f2: => List[A]): List[(A, A)] = Zip[List].zip(f1, f2)

def lzip3[A](fa: => List[A], faa: => List[(A, A)]): List[(A, (A, A))] = Zip[List].zip(fa, faa)

def lzip4[A](fa: => List[A], faaa: => List[(A, (A, A))]): List[(A, (A, (A, A)))] = Zip[List].zip(fa, faaa)

def lzip5[A](fa: => List[A], faaaa: => List[(A, (A, (A, A)))]): List[(A, (A, (A, (A, A))))] = Zip[List].zip(fa, faaaa)


def zip5[A](l1: List[A], l2: List[A], l3: List[A], l4: List[A], l5: List[A]): List[(A, (A, (A, (A, A))))] =
lzip5(l1, lzip4(l2, lzip3(l3, lzip2(l4, l5))))
```

Comment: The standard `Applicative` instance will not `zip`, it will perform the cartesian product. Depending on the length, that can be quite a long result.

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz Thank you! Sorry for the dumb question! [embarrassment]  ;-)

Comment: No worries! Not a dumb questions at all!